# Items floating over another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Really simple issue, really difficult fix. I have these images that on click fade in a div over-top of them. On desktop they display independently, but on mobile - tablet they stack on one another.

[image: My issue]

Things I've tried:

- Clearfix
- Table display
- Grid System

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/xzabitor/ysv6tgyw/2/)

JS/CSS/HTML/DEMO

```js
(function() {
    
    /* == GLOBAL DECLERATIONS == */
    TouchMouseEvent = {
        DOWN: "touchmousedown",
        UP: "touchmouseup",
        MOVE: "touchmousemove"
    }
   
    /* == EVENT LISTENERS == */
    var onMouseEvent = function(event) {
        var type;
        
        switch (event.type) {
            case "mousedown": type = TouchMouseEvent.DOWN; break;
            case "mouseup":   type = TouchMouseEvent.UP;   break;
            case "mousemove": type = TouchMouseEvent.MOVE; break;
            default: 
                return;
        }
        
        var touchMouseEvent = normalizeEvent(type, event, event.pageX, event.pageY);      
        $(event.target).trigger(touchMouseEvent); 
    }
    
    var onTouchEvent = function(event) {
        var type;
        
        switch (event.type) {
            case "touchstart": type = TouchMouseEvent.DOWN; break;
            case "touchend":   type = TouchMouseEvent.UP;   break;
            case "touchmove":  type = TouchMouseEvent.MOVE; break;
            default: 
                return;
        }
        
        var touch = event.originalEvent.touches[0];
        var touchMouseEvent;
        
        if (type == TouchMouseEvent.UP) 
            touchMouseEvent = normalizeEvent(type, event, null, null);
        else 
            touchMouseEvent = normalizeEvent(type, event, touch.pageX, touch.pageY);
        
        $(event.target).trigger(touchMouseEvent); 
    }
    
    /* == NORMALIZE == */
    var normalizeEvent = function(type, original, x, y) {
        return $.Event(type, {
            pageX: x,
            pageY: y,
            originalEvent: original
        });
    }
    
    /* == LISTEN TO ORIGINAL EVENT == */
    var jQueryDocument = $(document);
   
    if ("ontouchstart" in window) {
        jQueryDocument.on("touchstart", onTouchEvent);
        jQueryDocument.on("touchmove", onTouchEvent);
        jQueryDocument.on("touchend", onTouchEvent); 
    } else {
        jQueryDocument.on("mousedown", onMouseEvent);
        jQueryDocument.on("mouseup", onMouseEvent);
        jQueryDocument.on("mousemove", onMouseEvent);
    }
    
})();


$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#P1").on(TouchMouseEvent.DOWN, function () {
  $("#P1A").fadeToggle();
  $("#P1").fadeToggle();
 });

 $("#P1A").on(TouchMouseEvent.DOWN, function () {
  $("#P1").fadeToggle();
  $("#P1A").fadeToggle();
 });
 
 $("#P2").on(TouchMouseEvent.DOWN, function () {
  $("#P2A").fadeToggle();
  $("#P2").fadeToggle();
 });

 $("#P2A").on(TouchMouseEvent.DOWN, function () {
  $("#P2").fadeToggle();
  $("#P2A").fadeToggle();
 });
 
 $("#P3").on(TouchMouseEvent.DOWN, function () {
  $("#P3A").fadeToggle();
  $("#P3").fadeToggle();
 });

 $("#P3A").on(TouchMouseEvent.DOWN, function () {
  $("#P3").fadeToggle();
  $("#P3A").fadeToggle();
 });

 $("#P4").on(TouchMouseEvent.DOWN, function () {
  $("#P4A").fadeToggle();
  $("#P4").fadeToggle();
 });

 $("#P4A").on(TouchMouseEvent.DOWN, function () {
  $("#P4").fadeToggle();
  $("#P4A").fadeToggle();
 });
 
});
```

```css
/* line 7, style.scss */
.work {
  padding: 275px 0 550px 0;
}
/* line 11, style.scss */
.work .ic {
  width: 87.5%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* line 15, style.scss */
.work .ic .I1 {
  background: url(../img/hi.png) no-repeat center;
  background-position: 0% 100%;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
@media (min-width: 320px) {
  /* line 15, style.scss */
  .work .ic .I1 {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1240px) {
  /* line 15, style.scss */
  .work .ic .I1 {
    margin-left: 25px;
  }
}
/* line 41, style.scss */
.work .ic h1 {
  padding: 25px 0;
}
/* line 45, style.scss */
.work .ic .ih {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
@media (min-width: 320px) {
  /* line 45, style.scss */
  .work .ic .ih {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* line 45, style.scss */
  .work .ic .ih {
    width: 46%;
    padding: 0 25px 10px 0;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1240px) {
  /* line 45, style.scss */
  .work .ic .ih {
    width: 21.875%;
    padding: 0 0 10px 30px;
  }
}
/* line 69, style.scss */
.work .ic .ih .h1 {
  font-size: 1.15em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
/* line 71, style.scss */
.work .ic .ih .works {
  position: relative;
}
/* line 73, style.scss */
.work .ic .ih img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
/* line 75, style.scss */
.work .ic .ih div {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 25px;
  width: 85%;
}
@media (min-width: 320px) {
  /* line 75, style.scss */
  .work .ic .ih div {
    padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* line 75, style.scss */
  .work .ic .ih div {
    padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1240px) {
  /* line 75, style.scss */
  .work .ic .ih div {
    padding: 10px 0 10px 40px;
  }
}
/* line 100, style.scss */
.work .ic .ih .b1 {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  background: #2980b9;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px 13px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 35px;
  -moz-border-radius: 35px;
  border-radius: 35px;
}

/* line 111, style.scss */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: " ";
  /* 1 */
  display: table;
  /* 2 */
}

/* line 116, style.scss */
.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}

/* line 120, style.scss */
.cf {
  *zoom: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="work cf" id="W">
    <div class="ic cf">
         <h1><span class="I1"></span><span>Work</span></h1>

        <div class="works">
            <div class="ih">
                <img src="img/p1.png" id="P1" style="display: block;">
                <div id="P1A" style="display: none;"> <span class="h1"> 3-2-1 Bread </span>

                    <p>3-2-1 Bread is a national relief program which fights hunger and poverty through generosity and love.</p> <a href="piece1/index.html" target="_blank" class="b1"> Go </a>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ih">
                <img src="img/h.png" id="P2" style="display: block;">
                <div id="P2A" style="display: none;"> <span class="h1"> Radarda </span>

                    <p>Such a beautiful title.</p> <a href="piece2/index.html" target="_blank" class="b1"> Go </a>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ih">
                <img src="img/h.png" id="P3">
                <div id="P3A"> <span class="h1"> Radarda </span>

                    <p>Such a beautiful title.</p> <a href="piece3/index.html" target="_blank" class="b1"> Go </a>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ih">
                <img src="img/h.png" id="P4">
                <div id="P4A"> <span class="h1"> Radarda </span>

                    <p>Such a beautiful title.</p> <a href="piece4/index.html" target="_blank" class="b1"> Go </a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Solution fixing 1: It seems when the images are toggled to fade the *parent divs* height is removed, so when the div holding the text fades in,  it's not even being recognized, as in the height isn't added until after the effect, so the other IH (or columns) decide to stack. Going to try setting a permanent height to the parent div.

Solution fixing 2: Seems adding a fixed height to the parent div, and a height: 100% to it's children elements eliminated the overlapping, however now the image won't stay in proportion.

Comment: I don't quite understand the issue or maybe I don't understand what you want to have happen or not happen.  Can you describe it a little more?

Comment: Sure thing, check the info before JSFIDDLE in a minute.

Comment: Added an image in to visually describe my problem.

Comment: Okay now I see what is happening.

Comment: See solution fixing below code for further explanation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the main issue is that the way your elements are set up the containing div with the class ih is collapsing when the image that it contains is set to display: none.  This is what you'd expect.  A block level element has 0 height when it contains no elements unless you expressly give it a height.  The result is the other ih elements, which have float: left applied, do just that: They float left.

There are two ways to handle this without completely gutting your css. The first is to use opacity:0 to fade out the image so that it's hidden but still in the document flow.  The second is give the .ih div some height.

### [DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/ysv6tgyw/8/)

#### Use Opacity and CSS Transitions

The benefit here is that you're using CSS to handle the transitions.  This makes a little better separation of concerns, but the draw back is that IE8 and IE9 don't support transitions, so in those older browsers the content will just "jump" between opacity states rather than fade in and out smoothly.

The only changes in your markup are to add two classes to the div that contains your text (the ones with the P*x*A ids).  I called them .works-text and .hide:

```
        <div class="ih">
            <img src="img/p1.png" id="P1" />
            <div id="P1A" class="works-text hide">  
                <span class="h1"> 3-2-1 Bread </span>
                <p>3-2-1 Bread is a national relief program which fights hunger and poverty through generosity and love.</p>    
                <a href="piece1/index.html" target="_blank" class="b1"> Go </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Then you'll need to add two helper classes: show and hide, to your CSS and add the transitions to the existing rules for your image and text div:

```
.work .ic .ih img {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease; /*Add this*/
    transition: opacity .5s ease; /*Add this*/
}
.work .ic .ih div {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:25px;
    width:85%;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease; /*Add this*/
    transition: opacity .5s ease; /*Add this*/
}
/*Create these new classes*/
.show {
    opacity: 1;
}
.hide {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Now for the Javascript, it's not necessary to target the elements via their ids.  You can replace ALL of those eventhandlers with just one!  Using `$(this)` you can target just the element that dispatched the event.  Then you can use the `find()` method to target just the children of that element.  The `toggleClass()` method can accept a string with two comma-separated values that tell it to toggle between the classes with those names.  CSS handles the fading in/out.

```
$('.ih').on(TouchMouseEvent.DOWN, function () {
    $(this).find('img').toggleClass('show, hide');
    $(this).find('.works-text').toggleClass('show, hide');
});
```

### [DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/ysv6tgyw/10/)

#### Use Min-Height

This approach is arguably easier to do given your current markup and styles, but it has the drawback of not really being responsive.  Of course, you can adjust the min-height values in your media queries to approximate responsiveness.

The markup here is identical to the first option, except that we no longer need the hide class.  Just add the works-text class to the text divs.

```
<div id="P1A" class="works-text">
```

Then in the css, add your min-height values and the works-text class rule:

```
.work .ic .ih {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    min-height: 350px; /*give your div some min-height that is going to be large enough so that the floats are maintained*/
}
.works-text {
    display: none; /*so we don't use inline styles*/
}
```

Finally, to simplify the javascript, follow the same pattern as in the first demo, creating a single handler for all of the elements.

```
$('.ih').on(TouchMouseEvent.DOWN, function () {
    $(this).find('img').fadeToggle();
    $(this).find('.works-text').fadeToggle();
});
```

Comment: Man you really simplified this... I just managed to solve the issue by setting min-height: 100% and setting height to a fixed amount, but this just blows that away and simplifies it! Thanks so much!